# Jquery Cycle Fade transition not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cycle, fade, transition

I am new to StackOverflow, so I hope everyone will bear with me. I am a webdesigner with some experience with Jquery, but I'm admittedly not great with it. I mostly use plugins and can do some adaptations to the code when necessary.

I am currently working on a photography website that uses a liquid layout. I have incorporated the Jquery cycle plugin on the home page to help showcase the photographs. I originally had problems with the plugin, since it uses a lot of absolute positioning. I was eventually able to figure those problems out with the help of some code I found while researching the issue (I've lost the website I found the code on, so if anyone recognizes it, I'd be happy to give credit).

I've now got the page working perfectly except for one problem - IE won't generate the fade transition. It will show the first image, blank out the entire screen, then show the next image. I've spent hours researching the problem and haven't found a solution. I did find one forum where someone suggested adding fixed heights and widths to the cycling elements, but this fix didn't work for me. It did make the images fade in, but they disappeared and created the blank screen again before fading in the next image.

The fade works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. I currently don't have the fade on the site, but for reference, here is the url: http://www.jnicholasphoto.com

Here is the Javascript:

```
SetHeightToTallestChild('.slideshow');
$(function() {
  $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollDown',               
        speed: 2000,
        timeout:5000,
        random: 1,
        cleartypeNoBg:true
    });
});  
$(window).resize(function() {
  SetHeightToTallestChild('.slideshow');
});



 });
function SetHeightToTallestChild(i) {
var tallest = 0;
$(i).children().each(function(){
  var h = $(this).height();
  if(h > tallest)
  tallest = h;
});
$(i).height(tallest);
}
```

HTML:

```
div class='photo floatr' id='photo'> 
    <div class='slideshow cycle-main-frame clearfix' > 
        <div class='cycle-main-frame-row'> <img src="images/collage1.png"  alt='J Nicholas Photography' /></div> 
        <div class='cycle-main-frame-row'> <img src="images/collage2.png"  alt='J Nicholas Photography' /></div> 
        <div class='cycle-main-frame-row'> <img src="images/three.png"  alt='J Nicholas Photography' /></div> 
        <div class='cycle-main-frame-row'> <img src="images/collage3.png"  alt='J Nicholas Photography' /></div> 
        <div class='cycle-main-frame-row'> <img src="images/collage4.png"  alt='J Nicholas Photography' /></div> 

    </div>
```

CSS (relevant to the cycle images):

```
.photo {
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 65%;
  }
.photo img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 8px solid #2F2E29;
  border-right: none;
  }
.cycle-main-frame {
  width: auto !important;
  position: relative !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
.cycle-main-frame-row {
  width: auto !important;
  position: relative !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

On

```
$(function() {
  $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollDown',               
        speed: 2000,
        timeout:5000,
        random: 1,
        cleartypeNoBg:true
    });
});
```

change the fx portion to

```
        fx: 'fade',
```

Comment: I've done that. It's on "scrollDown" right now because it doesn't glitch out in IE.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 Doesn't support fading of transparent PNG's. IE 9 does it fine.

you are going to want to create an `if` statement and detect opacity support:

```
if(!jquery.support.opacity) {

    // run IE slideshow

} else {

    // run slideshow for browsers that support opacity

}
```